# Missing url parameters in internet explorer

Tags: facebook-access-token

I was following the tutorial at [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) to get access tokens for accessing Facebook from a web browser. Basically, this tutorial instructs people to get a URL in form of

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
    &state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE
    &scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
```

Then the user logs in in a dialog. Afterwards, the web browser will go to the redirect_uri followed by an access time and an expiration time in form of

```
YOUR_REDIRECT_URI#
    access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
   &expires_in=NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_UNTIL_TOKEN_EXPIRES
```

It worked fine with Chrome and Firefox. But IE won't show the access token after the redirect_uri. Actually it does not show any parameters in the return url. I have tried IE on two different computers, with the same problem occurring.

Anybody knows why the problem occurs and how to fix it? Any help is much appreciated!